# How to access MVC application after deployed to remote server IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, web-deployment, publishing

I have deployed my MVC Application to a clients remote server and it runs fine when I "Browse" from IIS, how do I access this from outside of this Remote server ? If I put the Remote Servers IP in my browser, it doesnt display anything ?

**EDIT**

@Spotted, as requested, this is what I have in my site bindings:
[image]

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which IIS bindings are defined for the site hosting your application ?

Comment: Are you referring to the site bindings for my application ?

Comment: Yes. Can you post them please ? Also, is your remote server normally accessible from outside ?

Comment: I have added the image as requested, I hope this is what you were looking for. So this is a brand new server, I can only RDP to this server when connected via a VPN, could this make a difference ? PS: When I type in the Servers IP address in the browser in the server, it opens my log in page, but does not work when I type the IP in my browser ? I would think that If I am on the VPN, it should also work, considering I can RDP to the server ?

Comment: Yes this could make a big differerence. First make sure the server is accessible from the outside world. One possibility is configuring [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) in the gateway. Typically redirect each request from <public_ip>:80 to <private_id_your_remote_server>:80.

Comment: If your server is only accessible by VPN then you need to try access that site via the VPN. Putting the IP of server should at least show you the IIS screen of the default web site

Comment: @SeanT I am connected to the VPN and putting in the remote servers IP give me a "This site cannot be reached" message. Correct me if I am wrong, If I am connected to the VPN, then I am effectively on the same network as that server ? So what am I missing that is not allowing me to access my MVC app from a browser outside of the remote server ? Sorry this is really all new to me...

Comment: I have added an inbound and outbound rule in the firewall for port 80 as well, and still getting the same error message in the browser as explained above.... :(

Comment: Well there are numerous things it can be and the only way is to rule them out unfortunately. It could be a network issue where a router isn't allowing you get to that ip. Have you deployed your site to the Default Web Page in IIS?

Comment: Your binding says http, is it https?

Comment: I have deployed it to the Default Web Site yes, I have also tried a different web site, but results were the same, so stopped the other one and am using the Default Web Site. The router issue you mentioned could be valid(I just read something about allowing an IP on a router, but I dont have access to this) - No the binding is http if I am correct, I didnt enable https when I developed the Mvc App. I dont mean to be a pain, I just dont even know what to look for, so IF you do have a site that has what I can troubleshoot to try get this working, perhaps this would be less frustrating for you ?